# Hearing Echo When Using Twilio Video Chat SDK In iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, video-conferencing, twilio-functions

Recently create an app for video conference with ***TWILIO CLIENT IOS***.
Hearing back the echo every time. Any solution for fixing this issue?

Comment: Are you testing the call with two devices in the same room?

Comment: Yes same room and same network, But not that much close.

Comment: Is it possible that the echo was caused by the sound being fed from one device back into the other in a loop?

Comment: No no..........

Comment: Have you tried testing with the devices in different rooms?

Comment: Not yet, Now am going to test in different rooms , Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I have the same issue also. Same Network different room. when I speak there is a bit delay then I can hear my own voice from the phone speaker.

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same? I am using voice and video